# Display large amount of formatted text in my android app by clicking an item of a Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I have to make a "Tutorial" type app. So I have to display a lot of text (containing new lines, space), so I'm using a `Listview`. When I click an item of that `Listview`, it will have to display that formatted text.

What will be the easiest ways for me to do this?

Comment: get the text in onclick and pass it to another activity/show with dialog with scrollView

Comment: In which way is the text formatted?

Comment: What have te items of the list view to do with the text?

Comment: The text should be formatted like a standard paragraph. When i click an item of the list, it will have to show me that formatted text. How should i store that large amount of text in my app and display it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If storing that text as html(in resources) is an option, then you can use `Html.fromHtml()` to get formatted text that can be shown in a textview.

Example:

```
Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Wall of text</p>")
```

Comment: can i do this with a doc/docx (ms word) file ?

Comment: Reading docx file is something completely different. This works just for html.